# angular dynamic component load template from data

Tags: angular

creating an app which is a fancy e-book.  I want to define a page template with a fixed look/frame for each page.

```
<page></page>
```

template:

```
<h1>{{heading}}</h1>
<div class="page-frame">
  <page-content></page-content>
</div>
<footer>footer contents</footer>
```

within the `<page-content>` token, I would like it to read in data in form of a template with other custom tags, formatted as a normal template and interspersed with custom tags - not just HTML.  The `<page-content>` component, would then swap out/in new page definitions as the reader moves from page to page.

page 1 definition:

```
<p>paragraph</p>
<custom-tag1 key=value></custom-tag1>
<custom-tag2 key=value></custom-tag2>
```

page 2 definition:

```
<blockquote>interesting quote</blockquote>
<audio src="audio.file" controls></audio>
```

note that the individual page contents will be kept as data but in the form a normal template.

I have not found a way to do this without defining each page as a component.

Any help/pointers/comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called content projection.
Have a look at this video that explains better than words:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeCd0-sqM7o